# How to get results from this particular POST HTTP call in Google Script - works fine in python

Tags: python, post, google-apps-script

I was given this simple script in python

```
import requests

val = "id"

data = {
  'val': val,
  'type': '1'
}

session = requests.session()

response = session.post('https://www.someweb.com/modules/output/ajax.check_results.php', data=data)

print(response.json())
```

For security reasons I am not allowed to reveal the correct url.

I do not know python (I can run above code on my computer and it works perfectly) so I wanted to port the code to Google Application Script. Currently it looks like that

```
function getResults() {
  
  var url = 'https://www.someweb.com/modules/output/ajax.check_results.php';

  var data = {
    'val': 'id',
    'type': '1'
  }
  var options = {
      "method": "post",
 //     "headers": headers,
      "data": data
  };
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);

  Logger.log(response.getContent);
  Logger.log(response);
  Logger.log(response.getAllHeaders());
  Logger.log(response.getResponseCode());
  Logger.log(response.getContentText());
  //Logger.log(JSON.parse(response.getContent()));
  //Logger.log(JSON.parse(response.getContentText()));
  //Logger.log(JSON.parse(response));
}
```

The output looks like that

```
2:47:22 PM Notice  Execution started
2:47:22 PM Info    function () { [native code] }
2:47:22 PM Info 
2:47:22 PM Info    {Content-Type=text/html; charset=UTF-8, Expires=Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT, Date=Sun, 24 Jan 2021 13:47:22 GMT, Set-Cookie=PHPSESSID=ibdotvlrrec1q6glnbe8i0iu23; path=/, Server=Apache/2.4.38 (Debian), Cache-Control=private, must-revalidate, Content-Length=0, Pragma=no-cache, keep-alive=timeout=5, max=100, Connection=Keep-Alive}
2:47:22 PM Info    200.0
2:47:22 PM Info
2:47:23 PM Notice  Execution completed
```

the commented Loggers give me that

```
3:14:03 PM Error SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input  getResults @
```

I think that the issue is that Google Script takes a second to finish but python takes 14 seconds. It waits to get the results.

Someone could help how to make Google Script to get the results too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the documentation for [`UrlFetchApp.fetch()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl,-params). `data` isn't one of the available parameters. You should use `payload` instead and pass `data` as a string.

```
function getResults() {
  const url = 'https://www.someweb.com/modules/output/ajax.check_results.php';
  const data = {
    'val': 'id',
    'type': '1'
  };
  const options = {
    'method': 'post',
    'payload': JSON.stringify(data)
  };
  const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  console.log(response.getContentText()); // string
  console.log(JSON.parse(response.getContentText())); // object, if it can be parsed
}
```

The error you received was from `JSON.parse(response.getContent())`, because [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) expects a string, but [`getContent()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/http-response#getContent()) returns an array of raw binary data. As per my example above, you should use [`getContentText()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/http-response#getcontenttext) instead.

Comment: You are right. I captured XHR communication, copied cURL and used it in python and because it was working I used it in Google Script.